# Disable table in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I have many controls in table and I want to disable all the controls using JavaScript upon clicking of some checkbox.

I have google and found that we can't disable table instead all controls through loop.
Please suggest me, what is better idea

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple script to do this.

```
var table = document.getElementById('yourTableId');
var inputs = table.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
var links = table.getElementsByTagName('A');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].disabled = true;
}

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    // There are better ways to disable links, but 
    // this is the shortest code to do it
    links[i].onclick = 'return false;';
}
```

This should run very efficiently, though it won't change the style of the table very much. [Maksim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014581/disable-table-in-javascript/3014604#3014604)'s answer has a good solution for making the table *look* disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this solution, but its require Jquery.
[Disabling controls within a table - JQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786175/disabling-controls-within-a-table-jquery-javascript)