# How to disable all Element inside a div or table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a table that contains several text box and buttons.I disable my table using jquery by this code:

```
 $("#tbl").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

my table become disabled but when I double click on the button it become enable and I can enter characters in my text box too. How I can Disable all control inside a table?

thanks

Comment: Loop through all the child elements in the table and disable them, would be my suggestion.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You must traverse and disable all relevant elements.

```
$("#tbl").find("input,button,textarea,select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Will this also disable the #tbl or is this independent ?

Comment: Specifying disabled on a table has no meaning: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element

Comment: Could be a lot easier with `$("#tbl :input").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: To gdoron:  Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :input cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :input to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":input")

Answer (score 4):

use a div to layer over the entire table, essentially making it "unclickable". Checkout the BlockUI plugin for this.

Read more about it on http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview

or refer to already discussed topic
[Disabling controls within a table - JQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786175/disabling-controls-within-a-table-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

I think following code will also be very useful

```
$("YOUR_TABLE").find("*").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this

```
$("#tbl *").attr("disabled",disabled");
```

Ex:

http://jsfiddle.net/zafqd/

Comment: Gads no. Not only is this slow, it will apply disabled attributes to random things like `<p>` and `<img>`

Comment: Could be a lot easier with `$("#tbl :input").attr("disabled", "disabled");`